# How can I avoid Raam's krill in horde mode?

Tags: gears-pop

1. In the co-op/multiplayer horde mode of ''Gears POP!'', Raam throws
   krill (bats?) either down the screen in a vertical column or in a
   specific location. Is there any way to predict or avoid where
   they'll land?
2. Particularly, when Raam sends the krill down the center of the screen, it damages my player-character, so it becomes a matter of time before I lose stage 3 (three). What is the tactic for outliving the krill?